# URL rewrite suggestion

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

I have a core php website,in which user can login, update profile, add friends and all.User profile is resides on a link like `"mysite.com/userProfile.php?id=####"`. My client would like to make it SEO friendly, like `"mysite.com/justin"`.

I know we can do it by writing rules in ".htaccess" file. If so, I need to change all the places where user profile link present.Actually this is very big deal since I need to modify nearly 250+ php files.

Is there any short cut to do the SEO friendly URL with out modifying the links in the existing codebase.

Hope this will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues! It wouldn't be possible to make it work without 'perversions' (in beautiful way, I mean). Editing 250+ file is not necessary and all you need is to use find/replace function and apply it to the folder. It would be easy and provide you with the result you need.

Make sure to make backups before doing this! Because you will not be able to revert it, well unless you keep all of the files opened.

Why don't you simply find `/userProfile.php?id=` and replace it with `/userName`. It will be fast and efficient?

In order to use userName but not userID's you will have to write a small php function to extract userName corresponding to userID.

Other than that you could probably apply tricky solutions but I personally wouldn't recommend this!